# count and sum different values per each day

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

how count different values per each day ? and the total value for each day? in one request.

```
key1 | key2 | tdate | tview
1  | 20161123454647 | 2016-11-23 11:11:11 | view1
2  |  20161123454648 | 2016-11-23 11:11:11 | view2
3  |  20161122454649 |2016-11-22 11:11:11 | view2
4  |  20161122454650 |2016-11-22 11:11:11 | view1
5  |  20161122454653 |2016-11-22 11:11:11 | view2
6  |  20161122454661 |2016-11-22 11:11:11 | view2
7  |  20161121454622 |2016-11-21 11:11:11 | view3
8  |  20161121454679 |2016-11-21 11:11:11 | view1
9  |  20161121454684 |2016-11-21 11:11:11 | view3
```

I found to count the total of all values of tview per day :

> SELECT  DATE(tdate) Date, COUNT(DISTINCT tview) totalOfViews FROM mytable GROUP BY DATE(tdate)

I have a key (key2) which the concatenation of date and the number of a render because I don't want to hive two same render in the same day.

It's most easy for me when I insert a new render with 'INSERT ON DUPLICATE key2 UPDATE'. I update just the number of view with one request. I don't know 'INSET ON DUPLICATE' <2 differents keys> UPDATE :newview. Interesting question too ;-)

The date is a timestamp in my table.

I use php 7, MySQL and PDO to do statement.

One of interesting output:

```
day | totaView1 | totalView2 | totalView3 | totalView1+view2 |totalOfViews
2016-11-23 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 2
2016-11-22 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 4 | 4
2016-11-21 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 3
```

After i found to range date of request and compare évolution of number view per day. Example:

```
Day (currentmonth) | totaView1 | totalView1 (lastmonth) |totalOfViews
```

Is the "alter table" can do this result?

Comment: Please show us your expected output as this is not clear right now.

Comment: I edit the result

Comment: I found to have a simple result. Because after I will calculate average poucent and elasticity of views in periods. ;-) most interesting I hope

Comment: The question is clear now, thanks for the update.

Comment: I found in mysql that with alter table there is possibility of sum in different period. But I will study this after...

Comment: I don't think you need `ALTER TABLE` here, just do a regular query.

Comment: Concatenating two things together only to find out that you need them separate -- That was your undoing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT DATE(tdate) AS day,
       SUM(CASE WHEN tview = 'view1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totaView1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN tview = 'view2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totaView2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN tview = 'view3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totaView3,
       SUM(CASE WHEN tview = 'view1' OR tview = 'view2'
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totaView1Or2,
       COUNT(*) AS totalOfViews
FROM mytable
GROUP BY DATE(tdate)
```

Comment: Thank you !! We can use this too to SELECT on period ? This month      WHERE tdate BETWEEN DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL -1 MONTH ) AND NOW( )  And last month ?      WHERE tdate BETWEEN DATE_ADD( NOW() , INTERVAL -2 MONTH ) AND DATE_ADD( NOW() , INTERVAL -1 MONTH )

Comment: @julux Yes you can add this condition to the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thank you. SQL request is a sport !

Comment: Well I certainly try to stay in shape!

Comment: I will add on average and statistic results.

Comment: Do you think I can inject SELECT to get a past sum ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This is a question and answer site, not a forum.  So you should open a new question unless your comment is closely relevant to your original question here.

Comment: Example : SELECT DATE(tdate) AS day,        SUM(CASE WHEN tview = 'view1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totaView1,                (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN tview = 'view1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totaView1lastmonth FROM mytable WHERE tdate BETWEEN DATE_ADD( NOW() , INTERVAL -2 MONTH ) AND DATE_ADD( NOW() , INTERVAL -1 MONTH )        ),  COUNT(*) AS totalOfViews FROM mytable WHERE tdate BETWEEN DATE_ADD( NOW() , INTERVAL -1 MONTH ) AND NOW() GROUP BY DATE(tdate)